# C# Speech Recognition - How to turn off background adaptation?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition, sapi

I have created a new recognition profile via Windows control panel. I never use the shared recognizer. I do speech recognition from my app, with an instance of `SpeechRecognitionEngine`. The method below is executed whenever my app is launched. Yet, after a few days, the profile is adapted to my voice. I know this because the recognizer hardly recognize anybody else with this profile. When I just create a new profile, it recognize anybody without a problem.

So this method does not work:

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine.UpdateRecognizerSetting("AdaptationOn", 0)
```

and

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine.UpdateRecognizerSetting("PersistedBackgroundAdaptation", 0)
```